# Create more than 1 measure from single table column

Tags: ssas

I am a newbie to SSAS OLAP Cube. I need to create 3 measures from a single table column. Here is the table,

[image]

So, I have created 3 tables using Named query in Datasource View. But, it restricts to create 3 measure group for 3 measures. Is there any easy way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing how much access you have to create views on the database from which this cube is being created there are a couple of ways to do this.

***Option 1 - In the Database***
It is good practice to put a view over the tables that you want to build your cube against and point the cube to these views instead of the underlying database tables. If you create a view over this table you can create three columns in your view against the column you have specified above. In your data source view you will then use the view in the database instead of the table and as this view has all three columns they will be available to you to place in one measure group.

This would mean that your view will need to do the WHERE clause filtering and pivoting of the data.

***Option 2 - In the Data Source View***
If you cannot create a view in the database then you can create all three columns in one named query and thus have one object in the data source view that contains all three columns. This will then allow you to use those columns as measures in the same way that the view in Option 1 would have allowed.

***Option 3 - Calculated Measures from three DSV objects***
You could keep your solution exactly as it currently is and have three measure groups, each with one measure in them. You then set each of these measure to be **Hidden**, which will hide the measure groups from users. You then create three calculated measure in SSAS each pointing to one of these measure and set the display folder of all three calculated measures to be the same. When a user then connects to your cube they will see only the calculated measures and they will all appear in the same folder giving the appearance of being in the same measure group.

***Option 4 - Calculated Measures using Dimension Filtering***
If the value you are filtering on in your where clause in the DSV is brought into the cube in a dimension then you could instead create only one measure from the named query you have created. You can then create three calculated measures and in the MDX of each you will refer to the measure in your measure group and filter based on the Dimension attribute and its member values. You can then place these calculated measures in your measure group and set the original measure to be **Hidden**.

***Option 5 - Filter by the dimension attribute*** 
If you have a dimension with TxType in it you could set the Aggregation function of the measure to Count and then simply drag the TxType attribute from the dimension where it is located onto your reports to filter the measure according to its members.

I hope that helps.